# Не парсится цена

Tags: python, парсер

Когда запускаю код, должна парситься и выводиться цена кейса, но выводится пустая строка.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case'


r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find('div', class_='market_commodity_order_summary').text
print(price)


TOKEN_INFO = '######################################'
id_chat = '#########'
message_is = 'Цена на кейс: ' +  str( price) + '\n' + url
requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendMessage'.format(TOKEN_INFO),
             params=dict(chat_id=id_chat, text=message_is))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо парсинга, можно использовать "API" маркета.

---

Пример кода:

```
import json
import requests

def fetch_data(url: str) -> dict | None:
    # Функция для получения данных с заданного URL и преобразования их в словарь (JSON)
    with requests.get(url) as response:
        # Проверяем, успешен ли ответ с кодом 200 (OK)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return json.loads(response.text)
        return None

def main() -> None:
    app_id = 730 # ID игры
    currency = 5 # ID валюты
    item_name = "Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case" # Название предмета
    
    # ID валюты можно посмотреть тут
    # https://github.com/Allyans3/steam-market-api-v2/blob/4.x/src/Configs/Economic.php
    
    # Название предмета получаем из ссылки маркета
    # https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case
    
    url = f"https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid={app_id}&currency={currency}&market_hash_name={item_name}"
    
    item_data = fetch_data(url)
    
    if item_data is None:
        return
    
    for key, value in item_data.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Вывод:

```
success: True
lowest_price: 111 pуб.
volume: 81,219
median_price: 112,74 pуб.
```